# Should I trust these packages and ppas?

Tags: ppa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are “PPA's” safe to add to my system, and what are some “red flags” to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Should I trust these packages and ppas on Oneiric Amd64?
PPA:

```
ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
ppa:atareao/atareao
ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

Packages from ppa above:

```
Jupiter gnome-shell-extensions calendar-indicator oracle-java7-installer indicator-weather lo-menubar xscreensaver xscreensaver-gl-extra xscreensaver-data-extra gimp gimp-plugin-registry gimp-resynthesizer
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These PPA's you have mentioned are maintained by

- Webupd8
- Ubuntu-x-swat
- atareao

`Webupd8` is quite a trusted site. They provide proper well made stable packages. Many people (Even me!) use their PPA's. You should not have a problem with their packages. See their [home page](http://www.webupd8.org/)

`Ubuntu-x-swat` is also a great team. Here also many people use it (Me also, again!). You can safely use it but do not forget to read the instructions [here](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates)

`atareao` : I have never used their PPA but searching around on the net gives a hint that they are a bit trusted and also recommended by some sites.

Generally most PPA's you find should be stable with no "evil" in them. Just to be sure keep a point in mind to add a PPA only if some sites recommend them. Also  make sure to add only stable version of a PPA. Some PPA's provide development versions which might thrash your PC if they are buggy. So in the end the **choice is yours**.

Comment: Why do many and even you trust them? Just because many use them doesn't mean it is safe.

Answer (score 1):

Its upto you whether you are going to trust any of the untrusted PPA's. I mean to say the risk level depends on youselves.

Comment: While it's always up to the user whether what to trust, I don't think your answer addressed the user's question.  You might not know whether webupd8.org is a trusted site, and understandably can't vouch for what you don't know.  For your information, a site becomes trusted by things like recommendations (which is very prevalent in AU), bad reports and reviews that are not resolved, and buggy and conflicting library installs.  He asked for flags, which I think may include things, like, lack or reputation, complaints of buggy, conflicting and unstable apps.